# Updating Pulumi-Stacks after rotating Azure-Secrets

Tags: pulumi, pulumi-azure

We use Pulumi to create our Infrastructure in Azure. This Infractructure includes different Resources that contain secrets (Blobstorage, Cosmos, etc.)

Now we have the need to rotate the primary keys of those resources.

I noticed that the Stack-Configuration contains those information (encrypted):

```
   "primaryAccessKey": {
                        "...": "...",
                        "ciphertext": "..."
                    },
                    "primaryBlobConnectionString": {
                        "...": "...",
                        "ciphertext": "..."
                    },

Will this be any issue for Pulumi if we change the secrets in Azure Portal?
```